# Inefficient SQL query while excluding results on QuerySet

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

I'm trying to figure out why django ORM has such strange (as I think) behaviour. I have 2 basic models (simplified to get the main idea):

```py
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

Now I want to select rows from table `a` that are refered from table `b` that dont have some value in column name.
Here is sample SQL I expect Django ORM to produce:

```sql
SELECT * FROM inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_a a
INNER JOIN inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_b b ON a.id = b.a_id
WHERE NOT (b.name = '123');
```

In case of `filter()` method of `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` it works as expected:

```py
>>> from inefficient_foreign_key_exclude.models import A
>>> print A.objects.filter(b__name='123').query
SELECT `inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_a`.`id`
FROM `inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_a`
INNER JOIN `inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_b` ON (`inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_a`.`id` = `inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_b`.`a_id`)
WHERE `inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_b`.`name` = 123
```

But if I use `exclude()` method (a negative form of Q object in underlaying logic) it creates a really strange SQL query:

```py
>>> print A.objects.exclude(b__name='123').query
SELECT `inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_a`.`id`
FROM `inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_a`
WHERE NOT ((`inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_a`.`id` IN (
    SELECT U1.`a_id` FROM `inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_b` U1 WHERE (U1.`name` = 123  AND U1.`a_id` IS NOT NULL)
) AND `inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_a`.`id` IS NOT NULL))
```

Why does ORM make a subquery instead of just JOIN?

**UPDATE**:

I've made a test to prove that using a subquery is not efficient at all.
I created 500401 rows in both `a` and `b` tables. And here what I got:

For join:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*)
    -> FROM inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_a a
    -> INNER JOIN inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_b b ON a.id = b.a_id
    -> WHERE NOT (b.name = 'abc');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   500401 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.97 sec)
```

And for subquery:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*)
    -> FROM inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_a a
    -> WHERE NOT ((a.id IN (
    ->     SELECT U1.`a_id` FROM `inefficient_foreign_key_exclude_b` U1 WHERE (U1.`name` = 'abc'  AND U1.`a_id` IS NOT NULL)
    -> ) AND a.id IS NOT NULL));
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   500401 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.76 sec)
```

Join is almost 4 times faster.

Comment: Can you post your code that you wrote using exclude?

Comment: I'm not sure, because I remember that I finally wrote it in other way, but the problem was the same - an additional subquery instead of just joining.

Comment: @Wronglink Don't check only running the queries. Run [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) command and see the output. According to `explain` results you may create/modify some index. After that, try running the queries again.

Comment: What `explain()` command do you mean? Mysql explain show that I don't have any indexes on `name` field and it has to look through all table in both cases. And I don't see any reasons why subquery should run faster than join.

Comment: @Wronglink Place an index on `name` field, you will note the difference. (I suppose that `id` field has actually an index)

Comment: As I wrote I have 2 basic **django** models, it obviously means that `id` is a **primary key**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a kind of optimization.

While `filter()` can be 'any' condition, it makes the join and the applies the restriction.

`exclude()` is more restrictive, so you are not forced to join the tables and it can build the query using subqueries which I suppose would make the query faster (due to index usage).

If you are using MySQL you could use `explain` command on the queries and see if my suggestion is right.

Comment: It seems to me that even if it's an optimisation it not obvious at all. I'll make some measurements to test which request (subquery or join) is faster and write the results here.

Comment: @Wronglink For testing, think on tables with millions of rows and try joining them.

Comment: I've tested on 500k rows without index on `name` column. If I add more rows the situation won't change fundamentally - join will still be faster.

Comment: @Wronglink Think into this scenario: Very big tables with millions of rows (e.g. 10^10 in every table) and a busy server. If you join the tables you could get 10^20 rows combinations and if the server is short of memory then you're in a problem.

Comment: What will change in a subquery case?